# SurfaceView drawing on top

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I'm drawing some custom stuff to a Canvas provided by a SurfaceView. This is included in an activity with other views.

One of the states in my activity requires the `SurfaceView` to be hidden (`setVisibility=gone`) and shown again (`setVisibility=visible`).

> Gone works fine, but when i set it visible, it does not reappear until
>   i interact with the SurfaceView surface. See gif below, after the progress spinner disappears, the surface does not reappear, even tho I set it visible.

[image: problem]

Any suggestions? I've tried invalidating the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had a logic error in my code, preventing the drawing thread from restarting after being set Visible.